# iteratively processing list with a function

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a list that varies depending on the result of a function. The function is designed to return the sum of two consecutive elements of a previous list, until there are only two elements left. I am planning to use a `for` loop to get the sum, but couldn’t find the right syntax to make my code work. Is there a simple way of doing this?

This is my code to get the sum of two consecutive elements in the array, but I couldn't quite figure out how to loop it:

```
def pairSum(lst, n):
    sum = 0
    for i in range(len(lst) - 1):
        sum = lst[i] + lst[i + 1] # Get the list of two consecutive elements in the array
        y = (sum % 10) # Get only the units digit of the sum, which happens to be the sum modulus 10, or remainder
        print(y)

x = [1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2]

arr = x
size = len(arr)
pairSum(arr, size)
```

Comment: That's a list, not an array. The two mean different things in Python

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I would like to know if there’s a way I can loop my sum function until there are no more elements left to add.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functions should, as a rule, return a value rather than printing a result. Unless it's a function whose job it is to print, of course. In your case, that implies that you need to accumulate the sums you compute into a list. Another small point is that you don't need to pass in the size of your list. A list object already has that information encoded in it. Putting those bits together, you get

```
def pair_sum(lst):
    sum = []
    for i in range(len(lst) - 1):
        sum.append((lst[i] + lst[i + 1]) % 10)
    return sum
```

You could shorten this even further by using a list comprehension:

```
def pair_sum(lst):
    return [(lst[i] + lst[i + 1]) % 10 for i in range(len(lst) - 1)]
```

Now you can use this function to get a smaller list from your original:

```
>>> pair_sum(x)
[1, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
```

And you can call it twice:

```
>>> pair_sum(pair_sum(x))
[1, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4]
```

But your goal is not to call the function twice by hand, it's to keep calling it until the list reduces to one element. Since the function returns a list, you can keep passing that result back into the function, until the result has only one element:

```
while len(x) > 1:
    x = pair_sum(x)
    print(x)
```

The result is

```
[1, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
[1, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4]
[3, 6, 8, 8, 8]
[9, 4, 6, 6]
[3, 0, 2]
[3, 2]
[5]
```

A `while` loop is clearly the more intuitive solution here. However, you can also use a `for` loop. The trick is to notice that the size of your list reduces by one element each time. To get from size N to 1, you need to loop N-1 times:

```
for _ in range(len(x) - 1):
    x = pair_sum(x)
    print(x)
```